# Two dependent Menus in ASP.NET MVC 5 web application design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, menu, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, viewcontroller

I am using the ASP.net MVC 5 to build the web application.
It's little more complicated than the simple MVC example I googled. Not so sure what I've done is the right way to do.

A user is able to select the Region or an item *ID: {number}* on the left hand in the Menu 1. The menu is populated as a multi-level menu which means there are two levels of this menu, *Region* and *ID*.

Each level decides which controller to call. For example, When Region 1 id clicked, `RegionsController` will be invoked, and render a view for the content.

There is a Menu 2 on the right hand, it's a menu according to which level clicked, so it could be different menu items depending on whether Region or ID were clicked.

Menu 2 is the functional menu, such as Map, Record, ... For example, Map is a menuitem in Menu2 correspoding to Region Level.
Record is a menuitem in Menu 2 corresponding to ID Level.

The layout is showing as below, including two menus (partial view) and a content.

[image: layout]

Scenario:

1. User clicks on Region 1, call the Region controller to render the view on the right. Menu2 is populated according to the Region. A user is able to click any menu items on Menu2 to render the content

   When a user clicked on Region 1, call control action to handle  `/Region/Index/1` to render the view. I will save the Id = 1 to both the cookie and session in order to use when the Menu 2 menuitem1 or menuitem2 had clicked. So the content is decided by Menu 1 and Menu2.
2. User clicks on ID:009, call the ID controller to render the view on the right. Menu2 is populated according to the Region. A user is able to click any menu items on Menu2 to render the content

   Same as 1. When a user clicked on Region 1, call control action to handle  `/ID/Index/008` to render the view. I will save the Id = 008 to both the cookie and TempData in order to use when the Menu 2 menuitem1 or menuitem2 had clicked. So the content is decided by Menu 1 and Menu2.

Questions:

1. If I want to see the Region 1 and Map, I need to save which item (Menu1 item) was clicked. So I can render the content when the menuitem# clicked on the Menu2. The truth is every controller needs to get which Id in Menu 1 was clicked.

   Save click item

   ```
   SessionManager.SaveItem(id, this.HttpContext);
   ```

   Get click item

   ```
   SessionManager.GetItem(this.HttpContext);
   ```

   It is too annoying to do this in every controller. Is there a better way?
2. Menu1 decides which Menu2 menuitems displays. So I have to keep track of which Menu 2 menuitems shall be display. In the IDController Index action, I need to render the partial view with "Record" menuitem. On the contrary, in the MapController, I need to render the partial veiw with "Map" menuitem.

   How could I improve this kind of MVC architecture?

Comment: Why are you using `Session` and cookies for this? Just pass the values around as route parameters.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Exactly. Pass item Id (ex: ID=001) from Menu1 to the content. So I can render the content according to item Id.

Comment: So just do it :) You have not shown any of the relevant code - the controller methods, how your generating the links, content etc so impossible to help further